# Use Gmail to send and receive e-mail from an outlook.com account

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

Basically, I want to use my Gmail account to send and receive my e-mails from my outlook.com account. I want to be able to send e-mail as outlook.com from Gmail.

I am looking a lot for an answer to this problem, but all of the solutions seem very complex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### To "send as" your outlook.com email address from Gmail:

1. In Gmail, open settings and go to **Accounts and Import**
2. Next to "send mail as:" click on **Add another email address you own**
3. Enter your outlook.com address and press <kbd>Next Step »</kbd>

   - You may wish to uncheck "Treat as an alias" ([information](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338))
4. You need to supply the SMTP server, your username and your password for outlook.com. The SMTP server should already be filled in ('smtp.live.com') and your username is your full outlook.com email address. Supply your password and press <kbd>Add Account »</kbd>
5. An email message will be sent to your outlook.com account to confirm that you control it. You need to click the link in that message or take the confirmation code and enter it

You can now send email from Gmail with your outlook.com as the "From:" address.

### To receive your outlook.com mail in Gmail:

1. First, make your POP access is turned on in your outlook.com account

   1. Open settings (gear) and choose "Options"
   2. Click **Connect devices and apps with POP**
   3. Choose "Enable", choose whether to allow other systems to delete messages, and <kbd>Save</kbd>
2. In Gmail, open settings and go to **Accounts and Import**
3. Click **Add a POP3 mail account you own**
4. Enter your outlook.com address and press <kbd>Next Step »</kbd>
5. You need to supply your outlook.com username (your full email address), your outlook.com password, and the outlook.com POP3 server, which should already be filled in ('pop3.live.com').

   - There are other options there too, like whether to automatically label incoming mail, leave a copy at outlook.com, use a secure connection, and whether to automatically archive messages retrieved. Check the options you want and press <kbd>Add Account</kbd>

You will now receive messages sent to your outlook.com address in your Gmail inbox.

### *Alternatively*, you can have outlook.com automatically forward your email to another inbox:

1. At outlook.com open the settings (gear) and choose "Options"
2. Click **Email forwarding**
3. Choose "Forward your mail to another email account" and enter your Gmail address

   - Decide if you want to keep the messages at outlook.com
4. Press <kbd>Save</kbd>

You just need to ensure that you log in to outlook.com at least once a year to maintain the account.

### To import your existing mail and/or contacts:

1. Make sure you're signed in to your outlook.com account
2. In Gmail, open settings and to go **Accounts and Import**
3. Click on **Import mail and contacts**
4. In the popup window, enter your outlook.com address and <kbd>Continue</kbd>
5. You'll receive a warning that importing is "powered by ShuttleCloud" and that during import the connection to outlook.com may be unencrypted. Press <kbd>Continue</kbd>
6. You'll be asked by ShuttleCloud if you should give access to Gmail. Press <kbd>Yes</kbd>
7. You should be alerted that authentication has been successful and to close the window to continue
8. In the original popup, you'll be asked what it is you want to import: contacts, mail, new mail for the next 30 days. All default to "checked". Uncheck as appropriate and <kbd>Start import</kbd>
9. You should receive a message that the process has started and it may take several days to complete. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and the popup will close

Comment: I bring an update for this as of 2022. smtp.live.com no longer exists and has changed to smtp.outlook.com, so if your services have stopped, this is the only change you need to make.